# Наложение картинок в html

Tags: html, css

Я накладываю один рисунок на второй, но картинки image022.gif в браузере не отображается, но отображается в html-kit. Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

cтиль:

```
.layer2 {   
    background:url(images/image022.gif); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-position: center;   
    height: "195"; width: "350";
    position: absolute;     
    top:"50";left:40%;    
}
```

разметка:

```
<body>
<td><div style="background:url(images/560.jpg) no-repeat top center;" width="990" height="163">
<div class="layer2 ">
<td width="990" height="163" valign="top" style="background:url(images/560.jpg) top left no-repeat"></td>
```

Comment: 101

010 - кнопку видите? она для оформления кода специально придумана :)

Comment: в html-kit кнопку видно, но браузерах нет

Comment: В редакторе, блин, здесь, на хэшкоде) Нечитабельно же вообще.

Comment: Может это иза того что первый рисунок закрывает фон, как это можно уладить?

Answer (score 3):

Как минимум - уберите кавычки из css (width и height) и добавьте их к пути изображения) И желательно освоить полный синтаксис background. И какая-то мешанина классов и css, теги странные (`<body><td>` - это как вообще?)

```
<style type="text/css">
.layer1 {
position: absolute;
width: 990px;
height: 163px;
background: transparent url('images/560.jpg') center center no-repeat;
}
.layer2 {
position: absolute;
height: 195px;
width: 350px;
background: transparent url('images/image022.gif') center center no-repeat;
top: 50px;
left:40%;
}
</style>

<div class="layer1"></div>
<div class="layer2"></div>
```

Comment: <td> это просто много скопировал.
Это действительно иза кавычек Спасибо!

Comment: Не за что, галочку нажмите) И вообще у вас 0% принятых, тут так не принято)

Comment: Да, тут кавычки лишние.

Answer (score 0):

На будущее:
для отрисовки div-ов на разных уровнях используй CSS свойство z-index: int